# Amazon SES SMTP same content sent to the same email service (gmail.com) different results

Tags: dns, smtp, amazon-ses

I'm sending a newsletter and testing it when I try to send to 2 google accounts

account1@gmail.com and account2@gmail.com

Why does my email go the inbox of account1@gmail.com while account2@gmail.com is sent to spam?

**NOTE:** (same newsletter content are sent, account2@gmail.com was receiving the newsletter in the inbox before but now it's not. I did not touch any filtering of gmail)

DKIM and SPF are all set up except DMARC

I'm suspecting maybe the SES SMTP IP I'm using is blacklisted but I'm curious does amazon SES choose the SMTP IP the email will be sent according to it's spamminess?

example: 
If SES sees a spam on the sent email content it sends using their IP addresses that are blacklisted?

Comment: Can you repeat this behavior consistently?

Comment: not really always but sometimes it goes to spam then on other days it goes to the inbox folder